# Enable kinetic (flick) scrolling on MacBook Pro trackpad

Tags: macos, macbook, touchpad, scrolling

I can't think of a better way to describe it in one word, but...

When you use the track pad to scroll, but flick it and then whatever you are scrolling continues to scroll and bit and winds down.

Make sense? Can I do this on my MBP with the multitouch pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [Smart Scroll](http://marcmoini.com/sx_en.html).

Comment: Looks like this does the trick. I'll have to use it for a bit to see if I actually want the coasting and other things it provides, but thanks for the link!